# running a jar on windows 7 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, java-home

I have 32 bit jre and 64 bit JRE and JDK.
PATH has path of ALL 3 in them.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>java  -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

why this problem. Earlier I could get output for  java -version and still the 
jar would not run.
NOW when I manually enter the 32bit install directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin
```

and then run the jar from the bin of the above directory - I CAN run it.
Any clue what's happening.

Comment: "manually enter the 32bit install directory" means ? Have you installed using installer or copy the directory from somewhere?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing different versions of Java, and therefore it gets confused - one JRE is picking up something from another JRE. Don't put multple JREs in the PATH at the same time.

Comment: What is the kind of your cpu, 32 bits or 64 bits. Just reinstall a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Your path setup is not correct, Path should point to bin of only one version of JDK or JRE.

I suggest you use 64 bit JDK which is compatible with your applications.